# Append the -n element in list-series to another list-series if condition met

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have the following DF (with desired result hardcoded)

```
dfo = pd.DataFrame({"list1": [["test1", "test2"], ["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test1", "test2"]], 
                    "list2": [["notatest", "test3"], ["notatest"], ["notatest", "Test3"]],
                    "desired": [["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test1", "test2", "test3"], ["test1", "test2", "Test3"]]})
```

In which I want to add/append the very last element of `list2` (`list2[-1]`) to `list1` if it == "test3".

Tried the following to no avail:

```
dfo["list1_test3_added"] = dfo["list1"].apply(lambda x: x.append([i for i in x["list2"][-1] if i == "test3"]))
```

Could also be the case that at some point someone loses their mind and it's not "test3" but "Test3", so maybe a regex match would be needed.

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test last value converted to lowercase and if match add to one element `list` and last add to original column `list1`:

```
s = dfo["list2"].apply(lambda x: [x[-1]] if x[-1].lower() == "test3" else [])
dfo["list1_test3_added"] = dfo["list1"] + s
print (dfo)
                   list1              list2                desired  \
0         [test1, test2]  [notatest, test3]  [test1, test2, test3]   
1  [test1, test2, test3]         [notatest]  [test1, test2, test3]   
2         [test1, test2]  [notatest, Test3]  [test1, test2, Test3]   

       list1_test3_added  
0  [test1, test2, test3]  
1  [test1, test2, test3]  
2  [test1, test2, Test3]
```